# Aggregation sorting nested elements - $sort inside $push

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I am trying to group some entries inside a collection by Date, sort the days by 'Date' and then sort the entries inside each day by 'time'.

In order to do this I am using mongo aggregation to group the entries by day but I cannot order the entries inside a day.

My entries collection looks like this:
default collection - not sorted by any criteria

```
{
    name: "entry 1",
    date: 1457049600000,
    hour: 14
},
{
    name: "entry 2",
    date: 1487049600000,
    hour: 3
},
{
    name: "entry 3",
    date: 1487049600000,
    hour: 21
},
{
    name: "entry 4",
    date: 1487049600000,
    hour: 5
}
```

Code I use for aggregation:
- Groups all entries by day

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$dateTime",
        entries: {
            // pushes entries into a day
            // the entries are not push in any order
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        },
    }
},
{
    $sort : {
        _id : 1
    }
}
```

The code above groups my entries like this:

```
{
    _id: 1457049600000,
    entries: {
        {
            name: "entry 1",
            date: 1457049600000,
        }
    }
},
{
    _id: 1487049600000,
    entries: {
        {
            name: "entry 2",
            date: 1487049600000,
            hour: 3
        },
        {
            name: "entry 3",
            date: 1487049600000,
            hour: 21
        },
        {
            name: "entry 4",
            date: 1487049600000,
            hour: 5
        }
    }
}
```

I want to sort both the days and the entries contained by the day like this:

```
day1: {
    entries: {
        entry1: {
            name: "entry 1",
            date: 1457049600000,
            hour: 14
       }
    }
},
day2: {
    // entries sorted by hour
    entries: {
       entry2: {
            name: "entry 2",
            date: 1457049600000,
            hour: 3
       },
       entry4: {
           name: "entry 4",
           date: 1487049600000,
           hour: 5
       }
       entry1: {
            name: "entry 1",
            date: 1457049600000,
            hour: 14
       },
       entry3: {
            name: "entry 3",
            date: 1487049600000,
            hour: 21
       }

    }
}
```

How can I also sort the entries by Time. In this case, for the second day I have two entries but they are not ordered by anything. I assume I have to do some sorting in the $push part of the aggregation but I have no idea how.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the expected output? You have defined your problem well but it could be further improved if you can show the desired result from those sample documents.

Comment: @chridam : I edited the entry, Hope it helps. Thank you!